# How to apply filters twice on the same page in Magento

Tags: magento

In Magento category page, I am displaying product collection twice in two sets. Now the thing is I want to apply filters(layered navigation) and paging features independently on each set of collections. 
The problem I am currently facing is whenever I apply filters, its filtering both the set of products.
How can I apply filters and paging on their corresponding product sets?

Please check the following url for better understanding.
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/53435938/key-pieces-comparison-tool.jpg

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May be because both are referencing to the same object.

Comment: @sabreena, Can you post some of the code snippets from your Blocks and template files?

Comment: @sparcksoft, I am using list.phml file (app/design/frontend/default/[customtheme]/template/catalog/product/list.phtml) for displaying the product collection. For another collection, I have repeated the same code snippet in list.phtml and for filters I am loading catalog/layer/view.phtml file twice for each set.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same collection for both, and there is no easy way to differentiate the filters for each collection as it's using _GET. The only way you could do it would be to use Ajax. Each set would be populated dynamically from the filters you apply, and they would be loaded independently. Although, reloading the page would just set the two collections back to the same point.

Comment: Yes, Ajax is the only option. But I don't know how to implement Ajax on the filters. Could you please guide me how to implement this?